# Possible to change color of a button outside the activity class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have an activity with a layout and some buttons in it, I want to change color of those buttons. But there are lot more buttons so I want to change them using a method defined in other class. Is this possible? I tried by creating a new class which extends the current class. But it is getting force closed.

```
public class Color_change extends Calculate
{
    public  void test()
    {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
        button.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
    }
}
```

`Calculate` is a main class which extends `Activity`. And I'm calling as below:

```
Color_change a = new Color_change();
a.test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current Activity being displayed on the screen isn't Color_change the code you wrote will not function. If you want to have a separate class that changes the color of a set of buttons, I would suggest passing the buttons in some form of collection to the class that changes the button color. You could write a class like this:

```
public class ColorChanger
{
  public void changeColor(Collection<Button> buttons)
  {
    for(Button b : buttons) {
       changeButtonColor(b);
    }
  }

  private void changeButtonColor(Button button) {
       switch(button.getId()) {
           case R.id.one:
                button.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000); 
                break;
           default: 
                // set default color?
                break;
       }
  }
}
```

Then you would just need to make a list of all the buttons you need to pass to your color changer.

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.one));
//add any more buttons
```

Just be aware, that theming and styling in Android allows you to accomplish a great deal of these kinds of effects. I would be sure you exhausted your efforts there before turning to a code solution.

Comment: I got one more solution, just to make button public static and access directly from other class

Comment: You could do that, but I don't think that it is ideal. It will be easy to break down the line if you start using the color changer class elsewhere.Finally, if you do use that, be sure to not subclass from Caclulate anymore as that is not necessary. 

Also, please be sure to accept an answer by clicking on the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the buttons to the test method or the Context to the constructor class and then you could change the color.
Like in

```
public class ColorChange extends Calculate {
   public static void test(Button button) {
      button.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
   }
}
```

Also note the change in the class name to follow the conventions.